# Twig Template: Looping a two dimensional Array

Tags: html, arrays, twig

I have an PHP Array like this:

```
$fruits = array(
    array("Apple", 1.25),
    array("Banana", 0.86),
);
```

### What I wanted:

Then I simply wanted the HTML output like this:

```
Fruit: Apple
Price: 1.25
Fruit: Banana
Price: 0.86
```

### What I tried:

I have already tried looping like:

```
{% for fruits in data["fruits"] %}
    {% for fruit in fruits %}

        Fruit: {{ fruit[0] }}
        Price: {{ fruit[1] }}

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

.. which didn't work.

Only this worked:

```
{% for fruits in data["fruits"] %}
    {% for fruit in fruits %}

        {{ fruit }}

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

.. but it gave the output like this:

```
Apple 1.25 Banana 0.86
```

How do I get the result like I mentioned in "**What I wanted:**" section above, please?

Comment: Not sure why u are trying to loop the array twice. Just do it like [this](https://twigfiddle.com/ox1x9l)?

Comment: Because I don't (didn't) know how to. Will try your way once I'm back to my PC soon. Thank you.

Comment: In case of double arrays seems work fine: https://twigfiddle.com/2xa9wo

Comment: @DarkBee Can you please reply it as the Answer below please, so that I can properly accept it as an Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just could do this:

```
{% for fruit in fruits %}
    Fruit: {{ fruit[0] }}<br />
    Price: {{ fruit[1] }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```